# How to track how longer user is on app for react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

I am trying to count in minutes and hours how longer a user is on the app for and display it. I have got the app counting minutes I just cant seem to work out how to track when the app is active or not. Theres documentation on `appState` but I cannot figure out how to incorporate this into counting. Here is my code:

```
function Overview() {
const appState = useRef(AppState.currentState);
const [appStateVisible, setAppStateVisible] = useState(appState.current);
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = AppState.addEventListener("change", nextAppState => {
        if (appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === "active") {
            setActive(true);
        }

        appState.current = nextAppState;
        setAppStateVisible(appState.current);
        console.log("AppState", appState.current);
    });

    return () => {
        subscription.remove();
    };
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => setCount((oldCount) => oldCount + 1), 1000);

    return () => {
        clearInterval(id);
    };
}, []);


return (
    <View style={{margin: 32}}>
        <View style={{marginBottom: 32}}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 36, fontFamily: 'Roboto_400Regular'}}>Great!</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 16, color: '#878787', fontFamily: 'Roboto_400Regular'}}>Average mood 23%</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
            <OverviewContainer title="Weather" value="14 C" />
            <OverviewContainer title="Time on app" value={`${(count/60).toFixed(0).toString()} mins`} />
        </View>
    </View>
);
}
```

Any help on putting the two together be great, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can access the current appstate as well. How about something like

```
setCount(if AppState.currentState is active then add one)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this codes will implement it:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let id = null;
  if (active) {
   id = setInterval(() => setCount((oldCount) => oldCount + 1), 1000);
  }
  return () => {
   clearInterval(id);
  };
}, [active]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).